# How to create an array in a for loop in Liquid?

Tags: arrays, liquid, azure-api-management

I'm trying to create an array from a list of objects using Liquid syntax:

```
{% for operation in menuItems %}
      {% assign words1 = operation.Title | split: '_' %}
      {% assign controllerName = words1 | first %}
      {% assign controllersTmp = controllersTmp | append: '_' | append: controllerName %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to split the `controllersTmp` to get my array, but at this point my `controllersTmp` is empty.

Any help ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can directly create a new empty array `controllers` and [`concat`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#concat) to it your `controllerName` converted into an array using the workaround [`split:''`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters#split). The result is directly an array, without the extra string manipulations.

```
{% assign controllers = '' | split: '' %}
{% for operation in menuItems %}
    {% assign controllerName = operation.Title | split: '_' | first | split: '' %}
    {% assign controllers = controllers | concat: controllerName %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Maroine, was this working in API Management template as requested? I tried to do a similar thing but it looks like `concat` cannot be used

Comment: If controllerName isn't an array itself (which I don't think it would be in the OP's question), you'd need to use append in the last assign. And you could skip the split in the first assign.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me

```
{% assign otherarticles = "" | split: ',' %}
{% assign software_engineering = "" | split: ',' %}

{% for file in site.static_files %}
  {% if file.extname == ".html" %}
    {% if file.path contains "software_engineering" %}
       {% assign software_engineering = software_engineering | push: file %}
    {% else %}
      {% assign otherarticles = otherarticles | push: file %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is the definition of push filter? I get "undefined filter push"

Comment: I believe `push` is a filter added by Jekyll: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/

Answer (score -3):

you have to init your variable controllersTmp :

```
 {% assign controllersTmp = '' %}
```